# Shopware 6: Business Event issue, multiple order confirmations

Tags: event-handling, shopware

I have some question about the new Business Event handler, from the documentation: https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/Business-Events

"If you want the event to send the mail to the customer as well as to the internal email address, it is necessary to create two separate events with the same settings and store internal email recipients in one of the events."

So from what i understand here, it would not trigger the original e-mail template event, when there is setup an business event for an predefined event like order set to paid.

But i experience it still uses the original e-mail template setup, so right now my customers would recieve 2 order confirmations if i set it up after the documentation.

Anyone else got a suggestion for the right setup here?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by additional plugins in the shop. Try to deactivate them and try again.

You basically need two entries in the Business Event-System.

- Mail to the customer (table with addresses not filled)
- Mail to the shop owner (table with adresses filled)